# MySql is not updating column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add two columns into a database when a script is run. The problem is when the second column gets created it is of type `int` when I really want `varchar2`.

My query:

```
$query1 = "ALTER TABLE `keyword_table` ADD `".$currentWeek."` INT NOT NULL AFTER `".$previousWeek."_url`";
$query2 = "ALTER TABLE `keyword_table` ADD `".$currentWeek."_url` VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL AFTER `".$currentWeek."`"
```

The query when the variables are put in:

```
ALTER TABLE `keyword_table` ADD `07_07_2015` INT NOT NULL AFTER `01_07_2015_url`
ALTER TABLE `keyword_table` ADD `07_07_2015_url` VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL AFTER `07_07_2015`
```

These queries are how I wanted them however when the second query runs it creates the column where I want but as an `INT` not a `VARCHAR2`. I checked the syntax, I went on PhpMyAdmin and looked at the syntax it uses when inserting the column and it is the same as above.

Any ideas why it isn't making the column the correct type?

**Edits**

I ran the code like this:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE `keyword_table` ADD `".$currentWeek."` INT NOT NULL AFTER `".$previousWeek."_url`";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo $query.'<br>';
$query = "ALTER TABLE `keyword_table` ADD `".$currentWeek."_url` VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL AFTER `".$currentWeek."`";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo $query.'<br>';
```

Comment: So how did you run the above query? There could be problem with that. Better to add whole code... or do you want us to guess your code?

Comment: Added how I ran it, it creates the columns no problem however the second one gets created as an INT not a VARCHAR2

Comment: Are you using oracle?

Comment: No just php, sql and phpmyadmin, it is exactly how phpmyadmin would do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARCHAR2` is vendor specific for Oracle. If you're not using Oracle you should be using `VARCHAR(100)` instead.

For the most part there is little difference.

The difference is this...

`VARCHAR(100)` - the allocated memory is 100 regardless if there are only 50 characters.

`VARCHAR2(100)` - the allocated memory is only equal to the amount of characters input into the field.

Comment: Thank you, I always assumed that you have to use Varchar2 because Varchar was going to become something else, anyway again thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no datatype as VARCHAR2 in mysql. Please use VARCHAR instead.

For a list of datatype that mysql supports, please refer this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html